# Avoiding case expression ladder without monad transformers

Tags: haskell, coding-style, monad-transformers

In *Real World Haskell* [monads are introduced](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html) as a way to avoid the code marching off the right of the screen by using the `Maybe` monad. However what happens when the case expressions include other monads like `Either` or `IO`, for example?

I know the ladder could be avoided with monad transformers, but aren't they overkill for just an stylistic issue? Is there another idiomatic and lightweight way to deal with this?

**Update**: Here is an example:

```
stair s = do
    s <- getLine
    case stepMaybe s of
         Nothing -> return ()
         Just s1 -> case stepEither s1 of
                         Left  _  -> return ()
                         Right s2 -> case stepList s2 of
                                          [s3:_] -> case stepMaybe s3 of
                                                         Nothing -> return ()
                                                         Just s4 -> print s4
                                          _      -> return ()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such a more complicated case expression? (You can't write case on IO things, though - the constructors aren't exposed). As you imply, monads aren't appropriate for simplifying arbitrary nested case expressions, they should make sense for modelling the problem as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [the `errors` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors), which was created precisely for this purpose.  It allows you to unify diverse failing computations to agree on a common error-handling mechanism.

For example, let's say that you have two computations, one of which fails using `Maybe`, and the other of which fails using `Either String`:

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead as = case as of
    []  -> Nothing
    a:_ -> Just a

safeDivide :: Double -> Double -> Either String Double
safeDivide x y = if y == 0 then Left "Divide by zero" else Right (x / y)
```

There are two ways we can make these two functions agree on the same error-handling mechanism.  The first way is to convert the `Either` function to a `Maybe` by suppressing the `String` error.  This is what the `hush` function does:

```
-- Provided by the `errors` package
hush :: Either e a -> Maybe a

example1 :: [Double] -> Maybe Double
example1 xs = do
    x <- safeHead xs
    hush (safeDivide 4 x)
```

Alternatively, we can annotate the `Maybe` computation with a descriptive `String` error message if it fails.  This is what the `note` function does:

```
-- Also provided by the `errors` package:
note :: e -> Maybe a -> Either e a

example2 :: [Double] -> Either String Double
example2 xs = do
    x <- note "Empty list" (safeHead xs)
    safeDivide 4 x
```

The `errors` package also includes conversion functions for `MaybeT` and `EitherT`, too.  This lets you unify all your error-handling machinery to use the target monad of your choice.

Using your `stair` example, you would simplify this by getting them to agree on `MaybeT`:

```
stair = void $ runMaybeT $ do
    s  <- lift getLine
    s4 <- hoistMaybe $ do
        s1 <-           stepMaybe  s
        s2 <- hush    $ stepEither s1
        s3 <- headMay $ stepList   s2
        stepMaybe  s3
    lift $ print s4
```

Comment: I was actually using `errors` but only the monad transformers. It didn't occur to me that I could use the non-transformer functions to eliminate some monad stacks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Use a smaller indentation setting ) Seriously though, the following should do the trick in your simple example.

```
import Prelude hiding (mapM_)
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Maybe

stair = do
  s <- getLine
  mapM_ print $ 
    stepMaybe s >>=
    either (const Nothing) Just . stepEither >>=
    listToMaybe . stepList >>=
    stepMaybe
```

For other cases the operations `mapM, mapM_, forM, forM_, sequence, sequence_` of `Data.Foldable` and `Data.Traversable` would be the sole toolchain for you. That is assuming you have [the missing instances for Either](http://lpaste.net/56005).

However I would still recommend considering transformers, since they pretty much are the standard way of dealing with composition of different monads.

Comment: I'd consider this as a valid, too. I wonder why SO allows to only mark one answer as accepted.